# Reflect Value.Interface() panic: bad indir on CGo type after v1.15.4

Tags: go, reflection, cgo

I'm using a C Library called GEOS which provides a C-backed implementation for handling Geometric operations. A struct containing this C type was used during some reflection operations, but upon upgrading to Go v1.15.4 (Or any version after) this results in a panic.

I've isolated the problem, and it appears that when using a reflect `Type` to create a new reflect `Value`, a subsequent call of `Interface()` results in the `panic: bad indir`:

```golang
var test *C.GEOSGeometry

reflectType := reflect.ValueOf(test).Type().Elem()
value := reflect.New(reflectType)

// Panics in 1.15.4+
value.Interface()
```

The actual panic comes from within `func packEface` inside `reflect/value.go` where the following occurs:

```golang
switch {
    case ifaceIndir(t):
        if v.flag&flagIndir == 0 {   // here v.flag = 22 and flagIndir = 128
            panic("bad indir")
        }
        ...
```

Does it appear that something I'm doing is incorrect here, or is it more likely that this was a bug introduced in `1.15.4`?

Comment: If working code broke with no changes, I would at least start by filing an issue with the Go project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I reported the issue to the Golang GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45451)

Upon some further investigation, in the C code, `GEOSGeometry` was defined as an incomplete struct type:

```c
typedef struct GEOSGeom_t GEOSGeometry;
```

The developers created a patch, such that this fails in a better place, as opposed to panicking randomly when calling `Interface()`